# How to display specific rows/columns in a many-to-many PHP/SQL relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, many-to-many

I'm using a many-to-many relationship (using three tables - users, groups, relations) to connect users within a group. I am trying to find a way to display the users registered in a group. Here is my code so far:

Search for a group by name through POST form:

```
    $errors = array();

    if(isset($_POST['groupSearchSubmit'])){
        $groupSearchName = trim($_POST['groupSearchName']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupName = '$groupSearchName'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1){
            $errors['groupSearch'] = 'No group was found with that group'
                    . 'name. Enter a different group name and try again.';
        }

        if(!$errors){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                $searchedGroupRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
                $_SESSION['searchedGroupID'] = $searchedGroupRow['groupID'];
                $_SESSION['searchedGroupName'] = $searchedGroupRow['groupName'];

            }
            header('Location: searchedGroup.php');
        }
    }
```

Work in progress to display users in the searched group:

```
    $searchedGroupID = $_SESSION['searchedGroupID'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM relations WHERE groupID = '$searchedGroupID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $_SESSION['searchedGroupRelationsUserID'] = $row['userID'];
        $searchedGroupRelationsUserID = $_SESSION['searchedGroupRelationsUserID'];
        echo $searchedGroupRelationsUserID;
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '$searchedGroupRelationsUserID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['email'];
    }
```

Right now when I run the code by searching for a group by group name it is outputting "1718testuser@email.com" without quotes. This corresponds to the fact that users with userID's 17 and 18 are in the searched group, and userID 17 has the email testuser@email.com.

1) Why is it not outputting user 18's email as well, if it is successfully outputting userID?

2) How do I separate the values into an array so I can choose to display the emails in a table with a separate row for each user?

Comment: you really need to do all of this in a single query, using `joins`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**

When you run the following query, you are selecting only a single record. I think that may actually be user 18's email address? It's the email address of the last result fetched in the previous loop.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '$searchedGroupRelationsUserID'
```

Best bet would be to have a single query to select the users:

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN relations AS r ON u.userID = r.userID WHERE r.groupID = '$searchedGroupID'
```

Then iterate those results to fetch the fields you want.

**2)**

What you're doing is a good start! I'd suggest something like this:

```
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['userID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Tangential points**

- I'd be using PDO rather than mysql_* functions, and preparing statements. mysql_* use is strongly discouraged, and the code as it stands is vulnerable to SQL injection.
- You ideally want to split your display code and logic code. Often, this is done with templates. You'll have code somewhere that gets users (for example, *function getUsersInGroup($groupID) { ... }*), and you'll pass that to a template engine that renders something like *... {{ foreach user in users }} ... {{ user.userID }} ... {{ user.email }} ...* .
- I don't think that you'd usually use session variables for this sort of thing. Using $_GET means that the group ID would be in the URL, and so it's possible to share, favourite, etc the page for the users in a group.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your help! I actually didn't know about JOIN before, so now I have another tool I can use. I will definitely be reading/learning PDO now, if it means that my pages will be more secure. Also thanks for the encouragement! I've just started learning recently for a school project so any positive feedback helps a ton.